# sas to group by product when it is across multiple columns and could be repeating in each row

Tags: sas

My table looks like this where the product is across multiple columns and could be repeating. If it was in a single column and repeating rows. It would have been straight forword.

```
code        category    x1          x2       x3       x4....x20
---------------------------------------------------------------
fruit1      fruit        apple      apple   orange
fruit2      fruit        orange     grapes
fruit2      fruit        bananna    apple   grapes
fruit3      fruit        strawberry apple
vegetable1  vegetable    beans      tomato  tomato
```

expecting to achieve this:

```
 x         count(distinct code)  category
--------------------------------------------
apple       3                     fruit
orange      2                     fruit
bananna     1                     fruit
grapes      1                     fruit
strawberry  1                     fruit 
beans       1                     vegetables
tomato      1                     vegetables
```

Efficiency is also critical.
I tried this code:

```
data test2(keep=code category var);
  set table;
  array x[3] x1-x3;
  format var  $10.;
  do i=1 to 3;
    var = x[i];
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql;
  create table try as
  select distinct 
    var,
    count(distinct code),
    category
  from test2 
  group by var;
quit;
```

This works but was wondering if there is a method more efficient than this as sometimes I have 3 variables, sometimes 2 variables(product) sometimes just one. I want to remove a row if it does not have variable(product) and dedupe to decrease the table size in test2 table if this is only method.

Comment: So what did you try? Did you get error messages or just not the desired output?

Comment: Post what you've tried so far, please review the guidelines on how to post a good question and what's required: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Add `if not missing(var) then output;` to your code to remove the extra blank records. You may also want to look into `PROC TRANSPOSE` if you want a dynamic transpose. Since you want a distinct count I think you're stuck transforming and them summarizing, otherwise could add together summary stats but you can't when you count distinct because it would overcount.